# Use Strategy design pattern to modify internal data structure of a Context

Tags: c++, design-patterns

By definition, Strategy is a behavioral design pattern that turns a set of behaviors into objects and makes them interchangeable inside original context object.

**Question**> Should I use Strategy to modify internal data structure of a Context object?

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5731daa0668a1a98)**

In the following demo code, I used Strategy to modify the internal data structure(`i.e. Context::param_`). Based on my project requirement, a Context object always uses a unique method and there is no need to change the Strategy on the fly. Is this a good idea to use Strategy to modify the hosting object internal data structure(s)? If not, what a better design pattern should be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual ~Strategy() {}
    virtual void DoWork(const std::string str_command, std::unordered_set<std::string>* out_param) = 0;
};

class Context
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> strategy_;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> param_;
    std::string m_task;
    
public:
    Context(std::unique_ptr<Strategy> strategy, const std::string& task) 
      : strategy_(std::move(strategy)),
        m_task(task)
    {
    }
    
    void DoWork()
    {
        this->strategy_->DoWork(m_task, &param_);
    }
    
    void PrintMe() const
    {
      for(const auto& elem : param_)
        std::cout << "elem: " << elem << std::endl;
    }
};

class ConcreteStrategyA : public Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void DoWork(const std::string str_command, std::unordered_set<std::string>* out_param) override
    {
      if (str_command == "task A")
      {
        out_param->insert(str_command + " hi");
      }
    }
};

class ConcreteStrategyB : public Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void DoWork(const std::string str_command, std::unordered_set<std::string>* out_param) override
    {
      if (str_command == "task B")
      {
        out_param->insert(str_command + " hello");
        out_param->insert(str_command + " world");
      }
    }
};

void TestCode()
{
    auto contextA = new Context(std::make_unique<ConcreteStrategyA>(), "task A");
    contextA->DoWork();
    contextA->PrintMe();
    
    std::cout << "=============" << std::endl;
    
    auto contextB = new Context(std::make_unique<ConcreteStrategyB>(), "task B");
    contextB->DoWork();
    contextB->PrintMe();
}

int main()
{
    TestCode();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO you should stop thinking by (named) patterns, instead, think what you want, if you need an interface, then use one.

Comment: And it'd differ from situation, `Context` and `Strategy` is no help understanding the real situation.